# Can't remove a list item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I am trying to remove a list item.

I add an item in like so:

```
$('#btnAdd').click(function(){
        var text = $('#item').val();
        if(text.length){
            $('<li />',{html: text}).appendTo('ul.justList')
        }
    });
```

then remove it like so:

```
 $('#btnRemove').click(function(){
    $("#justList li:last-child").remove();
});
```

Why does the last list item not remove? Any suggestions? Thanks so much!

Comment: can you show us your markup mate

Comment: I'm very new to this.. Not to sure what that entails.. Sorry.

Comment: try ` $("#justList li:last").remove();`

Comment: The `M` in "HTML" is for `Markdown`. He's asking to see your relevant HTML.

Comment: What I am asking is for you to show us your `html`

Comment: Shree, that didn't work. Thanks though!

RobertAKARobin, so do you want me to post my entire HTML document?

Comment: Post this in jsfiddle mate

Comment: No, burgoyne. We just want to see the part that has this `justList` `<ul>` element. Posting an entire document is a great way to make people want to not read your post. :)

Comment: you have added the elements using class and trying to remove using id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your add statement I would guess that you need a remove statement like:

```
$('#btnRemove').click(function(){
    $("ul.justList li:last-child").remove();
});
```

If your add statement is working then this should be accessing the same ul

Comment: Thank you! This solved my issue! I was missing the ul. before I called my list. Again, thanks!

Comment: No Problem. Do be aware though that if you have another list <ul> with a class of justlist that it will remove the last item from both lists when you click remove

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem may be in your punctuation. Note the difference in punctuation between "justList" in `.appendTo('ul.justList')` and in `$("#justList li:last-child")`.

- `ul.justList` says, "Look for a `<ul>` with the **class** of 'justList'," or `<ul class="justList">`.
- `#justList` says, "Look for any element with the **ID** of 'justList'," or `<any-element id="justList">`.

Classes and IDs are different, so make sure you're using the correct punctuation: `.` for a class, and `#` for an ID.

Answer (score -1):

Please use . instead of # while remove as well

$('#btnRemove').click(function(){

```
$(".justList li:last-child").remove();
```

});